# Icon cannot displayed in different dimensions when Windows thumbnail size changes

Tags: icons, size, thumbnails, dimension

I create an icon with different dimensions and color depth, then built it into an application via Visual C++ 2008(as well as Delphi XE3). However, the built app will not show icon with different dimension when I view it in Windows folder and set the different thumbnail sizes.

The icon is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/6lgbcptlkofgfnl/Split.ico?dl=0

The app is at https://www.dropbox.com/s/9habgl5thfobebd/TestIcon.exe?dl=0

Comment: The standard reason is that the OS has seen your program before with the simple version of the icon.  It remembers.  Google "windows reset shell icon cache" to get ahead.

Comment: @HansPassant, I follow the instructions in https://neosmart.net/wiki/clear-icons-cache/#How_to_clear_the_icons_cache_in_Windows_7 to clear the icon cache from my computer. But this seems does not work. The icon still canno be displayed in a larger dimension.